# Why does IE8 version "8.0.7601.17514 CO" behaves like IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In a client place IE "8.0.7601.17514 CO" is installed and can not be upgraded to newer version of IE.

This particular version behaves like IE7, in CSS rendering, rather like IE8.

So, IE8 specific `<!--[if IE 8]>` is not useful.

Is there a work around, to just target just this version of IE8.

Comment: You're probably running it in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3):

It is very difficult to give you an accurate answer without some example or link to the site in question.  However, I expect that your client's Internet Explorer is dropping into [Compatibility Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_mode#IE8).

This generally occurs where there's validation issues with the site as displayed, or - for whatever reason - Internet Explorer deems the website it's rendering to appear better in IE7 mode than in IE8.

As a first step, run your site through the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org) and rectify any issues that it raises.

You can also force Internet Explorer to render using the latest available (ie: not compatibility mode) - [IE-Edge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This can be achieved by adding this meta tag to your page `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Do note, however, that MSDN only recommends this for testing purposes and *not* recommend this approach on production sites:

> Because edge mode documents display webpages using the highest mode
>   available to the version of Internet Explorer used to view them, it is
>   recommended that you should only use this document mode for testing
>   purposes only. Do not use it for production uses.

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable compatibility mode, make use of the *broken page* icon in the address bar:

[image: IE compatibility mode]

You can also use the debugbar (enable it by pressing F12 or using the *extra* menu) and control in what mode it is being rendered (I've got the Dutch installation, but you'll get the idea):

[image: IE developer toolbar options]

There is AFAIK no way to specifically target a compatibility mode of IE, but I also never have felt the need to. If your page is triggering the compatibility mode, then try to fix your page instead of fighting this symptom.